# Slide Out menu not sliding out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I've created a slide out menu but I also have a accordion for my menu which also uses JavaScript and j query.

For the accordion to work I used this "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

And for the slide out menu to actually slide out I used "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"

but I can't seem to get things to work. At the moment the slider is appearing from the corner of the screen instead of the side. Is there a way of getting both to work.

You see it on
http://teamnews.org/#

```
<script>

        /* Slide Out Menu code */

        $(function() {
            var menu = $("#menu");
            var clicked = false;
            $( "a.menu-trigger" ).click(function() {
                if(clicked){
                    menu.removeClass("menu-open");
                    $(".slide-out-menu").removeClass("slide-out-menu-clicked");
                    console.log('show');
                    clicked=false;
                }else{
                    menu.addClass("menu-open");
                    $(".slide-out-menu").addClass("slide-out-menu-clicked");
                    clicked=true;
                }
            });
        });

        jQuery(".container").append("<hr />");


        /* Accordion code */

            $(function() {
        $('#only-one [data-accordion]').accordion();

        $('#multiple [data-accordion]').accordion({
          singleOpen: false
        });

        $('#single[data-accordion]').accordion({
          transitionEasing: 'cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955)',
          transitionSpeed: 200
        });
      });

       /* $('a.menu-trigger').click(function(){
            $('.slide-out-menu').animate({left: '0%'});
        });*/

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your top margin is in percentage, change it to pixels and it will stay the same. As the menu gets narrower, the top percentage shrinks as well, and makes the menu items move upwards (and therefore animate left AND up)

```
#only-one {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Could I ask how you come that so quickly and knew you were right . Thanks.

Comment: absolutely =) my first guess was that the entire thing was gettish squished intead of moved, and hence scaled down in that fashion. Using the web-inspector in my browser i can select relevant html-elements and look for things that make it scale (percentages of margins, percentages of widths etc) and viola, there it was. I can then change this CSS in the inspector and try the result immediately